# Issue with Next.js form submission and file upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, fetch

I'm facing an issue with form submission in a Next.js project that involves file uploads. The form consists of various input fields, including a file upload field. However, when I submit the form, I encounter an error on the server side indicating that the uploaded file is missing or undefined.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function FormComponent() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    resume: null,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, type, files } = event.target;

    if (type === 'file') {
      setFormData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: files[0],
      }));
    } else {
      setFormData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { name, email, resume } = formData;

    const formDataToSend = new FormData();
    formDataToSend.append('name', name);
    formDataToSend.append('email', email);
    formDataToSend.append('resume', resume);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formDataToSend,
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Form submission failed');
      }

      console.log('Form submitted successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred during form submission:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formData.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>

      <label>
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={formData.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>

      <label>
        Resume:
        <input
          type="file"
          name="resume"
          accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I have checked that the file is selected before submission, but I am still unable to identify the cause of the error. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and provide a solution to fix it? I would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance!

I have attempted to handle file uploads in a Next.js form using the useState hook and FormData object. However, when submitting the form, I encounter an error stating that the uploaded file is missing or undefined on the server side. I have verified the file selection and checked the code for any issues, but the error persists. I am seeking assistance in identifying the cause and finding a solution.

Comment: can you try with encType=multipart/form-data

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Comment: NO, it doesn't solve the problem